# Dashboard to display test automation results from different tools

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, extentreports, pitest, mochawesome

I have got to create one common dashboard that can be used to display the execution results along with execution status and pass percentage from various test automation tools like

> api - mochasome reports,
> seleium- extent reports,
> selenium - cucumber reports.
> selenium - testng reports
> pitest reports
> etc..
> Which tool can be used for this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Datadog might work if you can upload the reports: https://docs.datadoghq.com/continuous_integration/setup_tests/junit_upload/?tab=linux

Still looking for a solution myself too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.